# Visual Studio EDMX Designer Tool API to add/drop models using code (EF 6)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My database has more than 500 tables. It's very slow to open its EDMX file in Visual Studio. Moreover, I cannot select multiple models to delete them. VS either allows to delete models individually or all at once.

I would like to write a script that can use the VS EDMX Designer Tool to drop/add multiple models without opening the diagram and interacting manually with the tool.

Comment: I worked with EF6 for years.  I think I remember opening the edmx once, maybe twice.  Just to see what it looked like.

Comment: How were you updating it then? Directly changing the XML?